# Modify a value in MYSQL field with multiple values(complicated)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Table 1 - users

```
id username items
1 Paul 1(0020);2(0001);
```

Table 2 - items

```
id name 
1 name_here
```

In my user's items I put 2(0001) which means: 2=item id, 0001 is the amount of it
Here is a function that displays my item list

```
function getitems() {
$username = $_SESSION['user'];
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","x") or die("Conexiune nereusita!");
mysql_select_db("skameron") or die("Baza de date nu exista!");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $username . "'") or            die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
        echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">Nu ai iteme in inventar!</td></tr>";
} else {
        while($itm = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $str = $itm['items'];
    $items = preg_split("/;/", $str); 
    foreach ($items as $item){ 
 
$temp_item =  preg_split("/,/", $item); 
if($temp_item){ 
    foreach ($temp_item as $temp_i){ 
    If($temp_i=="")
    {
    }
    else{
    $pieces = substr($temp_i, -5, 4);
    $piecesold = $pieces;
    $pieces = $pieces/1;
    //$arrnr = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"(",")");
    //$temp_i = str_replace($arrnr,"",$temp_i);
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id='" . $temp_i . "'") or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($query2) == 0) {
        echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">Nu ai iteme in inventar!</td></tr>";
} else {
        while($itm2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
        $temp_i = $itm2['name'];
        $temp_id = $itm2['id'];
        echo $temp_i . " <a href='items.php?del=". $temp_id."(".$piecesold.")'>Delete all</a>(". $pieces . ")/<a href='items.php?del=". $temp_id."(".$piecesold.")&nr=1'>Delete 1</a><br>"; 
    }}}}} else { 
    echo $item;     
}}}}}
```

I made the page to delete an item but I can't find a way to delete just the amount of items...for example to change this: 2(0100);1(0001); to this: 2(0099);1(0001);

Here is how I did to delete a value like this:

```
$delitem = $_GET['del'];
$queryreg = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET items = REPLACE(items, '$delitem;', '');");
```

I can delete with this page a value like 2(0099); and the others remain...
But I can't only change the amount of item which is 0099/1=99

Comment: Do you have a very compelling reason you don't split that information in to two different columns? And why you are storing a LIST of things inside a single column?

Comment: Any solution you get from there that does **NOT** involve redesigning your tables is going to be fundamentally flawed. You really really REALLY need to normalize that design.

Comment: You can't find a way to do this in MySQL, because MySQL doesn't provide this kind of function. If you store your data like this, you're going to have to handle the update yourself; as you've discovered, when you do the UPDATE, you need to assign the entire column value. You need logic which that will be overly complicated to implement using builtin MySQL functions; if you manage to get it implemented, the resulting expression will be so fugly it will be nearly impossible to decipher what it does. Your data design is whack; the code you need to manage it will be whack too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *really* should consider changing the layout of your data

```
Table1 - Users
Id Name
1  Paul

Table2 - Items
Id Name
1  SomeItem
2  AnotherItem

Table3 - UserItems
UserId ItemId Quantity
1      1      100
1      2      99
```

Now paul has 100 of SomeItem and 99 of AnotherItem

Comment: Ok i`ll use that way<br>I am new in this and i was thinking it`s better to use less rows:)